# How to repeat VBA code using For-Loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

I need help executing the first code for every ID in column H. I've tried establishing a "loop" and a "for next" to no avail.

I'd like to establish a type of "i = row number" and have a "i + 1" command that will perform the same task for every cell in the column

Any help is sincerely appreciated!

```
Sub GenerateAll_1()

'Copy the first ID in the list (cell H2) and paste it
    Sheets("Specialist Roster").Select
    Range("H2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Weekly Productivity").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
'My code that saves as pdf based on other criteria goes here

'REPEAT task for the cells H3, H4... H260
```

Comment: `for each cell in range`

Comment: So, you need to copy each cell in column H, and place in "Weekly Productivity" sheet? I assume in the next available place? What are you trying to accomplish? If you just need to do all cells in H, why not just copy the whole column (`Range("H:H").Copy`)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion... "Weekly Productivity" is a report to be individually generated for each Specialist. Whenever an employee ID is entered into the input cell, that person's details is populated. Currently, in order to generate all the pdfs, the IDs have to be entered manually or selected from a drop list. Column H in "Specialist Roster" lists all active Specialist's ID number.         I am trying to automate the process of generating PDFs for everyone by way of telling the code to "go through this list and create a PDF for every ID in this list".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is really just to give you an idea of how a for loop would work here. It should be noted that looping is NOT the most efficient way of copying and pasting values between sheets. I think some of the other solutions better address the efficient ways:

```
For i = 2 To 260
Sheets("Specialist Roster").Range("H" & i).Copy
'here you need to specify what range you want to copy to
Sheets("Weekly Productivity").Range("H" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
 Next i
```

this is not a Great solution for scaling because it is hard coded to do rows 2 through 260. But it can be made better using some variables. Hope this is somewhat helpful...

Comment: I know, I just copy and pasted the OP out of laziness

Comment: if you clean up the `.Select`, I'll take away the dv.

Comment: you got yourself a deal!

Comment: Still have one, the second and third lines should be one `Sheets("Specialist Roster").Range("H" & i).Copy`

Comment: You can also edit it so you don't have to select `Sheets("Specialist Roster")` how about `Sheets("Specialist Roster").Range("H" & i).Copy` or use `with sh.`

Comment: oops, yep missed that one. should be fixed now

Comment: Thank you all! I used @archerbird's general idea along with Davesexcel's recommendation and the code ran. However, it stops after 18 IDs from the roster list.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a one line sub:

```
Sub GenerateAll_1()
    Sheets("Specialist Roster").Range("H2:H" & Rows.Count).Copy Sheets("Weekly Productivity").Range("H2")
End Sub
```

No loops are required.  If you want to avoid the values in column **H** below row 260, then:

```
Sub GenerateAll_1()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

    Set r1 = Sheets("Specialist Roster").Range("H2:H260")
    Set r2 = Sheets("Weekly Productivity").Range("H2")

    r1.Copy r2
End Sub
```

Comment: IMO, this is the better answer for efficiency and ease of maintaining.

Answer (score 3):

To only copy the data, as your code suggests (`xlPasteValues`), do like this:

```vb
Sheets("Weekly Productivity").Range("H2:H260") = 
    Sheets("Specialist Roster").Range("H2:H260").Value
```

Without loop.

You can even do it without code, and just put a formula in "Weekly Productivity":

In cell H2:

```
='Specialist Roster'!H2
```

... and drag down as far as needed.

If you really need the loop (because of other tasks you want to do based on intermediate results), then go for this:

```
Sub GenerateAll_1()
    Dim source As Range ' cell from which you copy
    Dim target As Range ' cell to which you copy

    Set target = Sheets("Weekly Productivity").Range("H1")

    For Each source In Sheets("Specialist Roster").Range("H2:H260")
        target = source.Value ' copy the value (only)
        Set target = target.Offset(1) ' let target point to next cell
        ' perform other tasks here
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't need to paste the entire column H into the weekly report tab. I need the code to 1. Grab the first ID (H2); 2. Paste that ID number into the weekly tab (H1); 3. Save as PDF; 4) Go back to the roster and grab the next ID number (H3) and paste it into the weekly tab (H2); 5. Repeat this same task for all the IDs listed in column H of the roster.

Comment: ArcherBird's example worked perfectly, but the code stops after a few PDF have already been generated for some reason.

Comment: I think that is more PDF-generating related issue, and deserves a new question in my opinion. You should there specify the library you use and provide some of the PDF generating code you have. It is quite a different question.

Comment: I added a loop as alternative. Maybe try that. As I don't know the PDF side, the source of your problems might still to be found there and not in your loop.

Comment: The pdf-generating aspect works perfectly and is not the issue. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You wrote under the accepted answer: *However, it stops after 18 IDs from the roster list.* Do you still have this problem?

Comment: No, that doesn't occur anymore... for whatever reason. Thanks for double checking. All help and insights are greatly appreciated.